# Blank page on creating a page on production site

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I am trying to create a page with some php code. I works fine but when I use a custom function in code then after clicking the save button it display a blank white page.
I have written the code in body field of a page.
Here is my code

```
$vid = 26;
print $vid;
print xyz();
function xyz() {
  return 'xyz';
}
```

Comment: Were you sure to select the PHP input filter and include PHP tags? (`<?php ?>`)

Comment: Yes I have selected the PHP input filter and include PHP tags.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure your input type is set to PHP, and not 'HTML Filter' or other such nonsense. . .

Also, I believe that you need to have the function FIRST.  Right now, in programming order, it's trying to run a function that it has yet to see.  Try putting the function somewhere before where you call it.

```
function xyz() {
return 'xyz';
}

$vid = 26;
print $vid;
print xyz();
```

~Terrik

Comment: I have selected the input type to PHP and I also try to add the function first. But I am getting the same problem.

Comment: The code that Eli posted unfortunately only works if you have your apache settings set to display the error messages, which you probably don't. . . (On a production site, you don't usually want your page throwing errors at users, ever)

I've checked your php and it works fine in my Drupal site.  Can you check your Drupal message log and report back what error it's throwing when you load the page?

Answer (score 0):

A blank page usually means PHP is throwing an error, but you can't see it because of your settings. Have you checked the error log for your webserver and the Drupal message log (in the admin section)?

You can also tell PHP to display errors by adding these two lines:

```
ini_set(‘display_errors’,1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: I wrote the above code for the errors but getting the same white page. Did not display any error.